# Инверсия или нет?

Tags: порядок-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, "Без подарка не останется никто!" - это инверсия? И вообще корректен ли такой порядок слов в предложении, если говорить о рекламном тексте?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Да, инверсия. Прямой порядок - это когда сначала состав подлежащего, потом состав сказуемого. Должно быть: "Никто не останется без подарка".

В рекламе инверсия употребляется часто, так что всё корректно и эмоционально - зазывно.

Answer (score 2):

**Возможны три  варианта:** (1) Никто не останется //без подарка.   (2) Без подарка // никто не останется.  (3) Без подАрка //не останется никтО.

Простое предложение строится по принципу тема (предмет) ― рема (сообщение о предмете). Первых два предложения разнятся местами (темы и ремы) с сохранением стандартной спокойной интонации.

А вот в третьем предложении применена **инверсия** подлежащего и сказуемого, что меняет расстановку ударений. Логически выделяются два важных по смыслу слова: *подарка* и *никто*.

Answer (score 1):

"Без подарка не останется никто!" - это инверсия?
Прямой порядок - это когда идёт сначала состав подлежащего, а затем - сказуемого. Согласна абсолютно с Людмилой.  В русском же языке существует свободный порядок слов  в предложении.  Это значит, что, в зависимости от смысловой нагрузки, автор может наиболее значимое для него слово перенести в конец предложения, изменив таким образом логическое ударение. Сравните: я приду ДОМОЙ (а не куда -то ещё!) или я домой ПРИДУ (а не приеду!).
Слово "инверсия" произошло от латинского "inversio", что означает - "переворачивание", "перестановка". Но это отнюдь не означает, что мы МЕНЯЕМ местами какие-либо члены предложения: мы просто ПЕРЕНОСИМ важное акцентологическое слово в самый конец предложения. 
Традиционно под инверсией понимают ЛЮБОЕ отклонение от принятого, обычного порядка слов в предложении. Одна из разновидностей инверсии - это СКАЗОВЫЙ порядок слов, когда мы только "переставляем" сказуемое перед подлежащим. Например, "жили-были дед да баба" (прямой порядок - "дед да баба жили-были"). Сказовый порядок слов используется в сказках.
Так что "Без подарка не останется никто!" - это инверсия, она здесь оправдана. А вот насчёт рекламного слогана ничего не могу сказать . Там свои особые правила.